# ggplot : geom_bar with many bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I m using ggplot and geom_bar for 188 categories versus continous values . 
As you can see, the render is hugly with vertical white spacing . 
How can I remove that ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the width parameter in geom_bar to 1: `geom_bar(width=1)`